# iCalendar: Recurring events are not correctly displayed in IOS

Tags: ios, ios8, icalendar, rfc5545

**Brief introduction**

Recurring events in my PHP-generated iCalendar file does not recur correctly with IOS applications.
They do recur correctly in Outlook 2010 and Google Calendar, but not in IOS 8.1 (iPhone 5S and iPad 2).

**Details**

The following file generates a calendar file fit for subscription from applications like MS Outlook and Google Calendar. The file contains a VTIMEZONE and a single VEVENT, meant to recur every friday from 7 - 28. nov 2014, four recurrences in total.

iCalendar file: http://www.elitesystemer.no/mycal_stack_example.php (full code below)

On both my iDevices (IOS 8.1) this event occurs only once; 7. nov 2014. This odd behaviour goes for the native calendar app as well as the Week Calendar app (site: http://weekcal.com).

The file works perfectly with MS Outlook 2010 and Google Calendar, but not with IOS. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any equivalent issue at the Apple forums. Neither am I able to test with an iDevice with a former OS version, nor with another smart phone at the time.

I have tested the file at online iCalendar validators like http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/ and http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ - perfect results without warnings / errors.

**Calendar code generated from PHP**

```
<?php
//set correct content-type-header
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=mycal_stack_example.ics');
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR<?echo "\r\n";?>
VERSION:2.0<?echo "\r\n";?>
METHOD:PUBLISH<?echo "\r\n";?>
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN<?echo "\r\n";?>
PRODID:-//Elite Systemer//Ver 1.6//NO<?echo "\r\n";?>
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE<?echo "\r\n";?>
TZID:Europe/Oslo<?echo "\r\n";?>
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT<?echo "\r\n";?>
DTSTART:19810329T020000<?echo "\r\n";?>
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU<?echo "\r\n";?>
TZNAME:CEST<?echo "\r\n";?>
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100<?echo "\r\n";?>
TZOFFSETTO:+0200<?echo "\r\n";?>
END:DAYLIGHT<?echo "\r\n";?>
BEGIN:STANDARD<?echo "\r\n";?>
DTSTART:19961027T030000<?echo "\r\n";?>
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU<?echo "\r\n";?>
TZNAME:CET<?echo "\r\n";?>
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200<?echo "\r\n";?>
TZOFFSETTO:+0100<?echo "\r\n";?>
END:STANDARD<?echo "\r\n";?>
END:VTIMEZONE<?echo "\r\n";?>
BEGIN:VEVENT<?echo "\r\n";?>
UID:f8a81b8613113296503aa6fca2b61ce5@elitesystemer.no<?echo "\r\n";?>
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Oslo:20141107T140000<?echo "\r\n";?>
DURATION:PT60M<?echo "\r\n";?>
RRULE:WKST=MO;FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20141128T150000<?echo "\r\n";?>
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=no:Friday<?echo "\r\n";?>
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=no:Oppgave: Friday\n<?echo "\r\n";?>
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=no:Timenesveien 33<?echo "\r\n";?>
BEGIN:VALARM<?echo "\r\n";?>
TRIGGER:-PT15M<?echo "\r\n";?>
ACTION:DISPLAY<?echo "\r\n";?>
DESCRIPTION:Reminder<?echo "\r\n";?>
END:VALARM<?echo "\r\n";?>
END:VEVENT<?echo "\r\n";?>
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing it seems to work if I remove the WKST rule.

```
WKST=MO
```

After all, the default value of WKST is MO.

Comment: The default depends on your start date.

Answer (score 0):

Mindblowing but it seems that ios simply does not do recurring events by day of week - a quick google found this Jan 2014 post:

> The ability to schedule recurring events by day of the week is missing
>   in action on iOS.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2091041/scheduling-recurring-events-on-ios.html
the link has some suggestions around it.   (and I love the final paragraph suggestion!)

I use google calendar on my iphone so I haven't noticed this before and find it hard to believe, but clearly it is a problem.

The only other way around it that I can think of is to offer an ics feed for apple calendar users that generates RDATE's for the recurring instances, rather than the RRULE.  Surely it should load those?

Comment: I don't think `RDATE` is commonly supported either.. but not sure about iOS.

Comment: yet another example of limited rfc5545 implementation !

Comment: IOS _is_ able to recur events from subscribed calendars. I set up a simple Google Calendar subscription with the same recurring event, and it worked flawlessly. So I think there might be an error in my iCal code somewhere, or of course, IOS might not follow the spec correctly.